# Is File type available in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) lists `File` type. Is this type available in Nodejs environment? If yes, directly or should I import some module -- which?

Comment: @Rob Doesn't matter. `File` is part of the **browser** API. NodeJS doesn't run in the browser so it doesn't have `File`.

Comment: Note that the `File` type handles file `<inputs>` in web pages. Since node.js is by default not running as a browser then it does not have the File type. However, node.js compiled with a web browser like nwjs or Electron or even Phantom.js most probably have the File type

Comment: If you want to do file related stuff on node.js then you probably want node's built-in `fs` module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`File` is part of the [Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API), not a part of the standard Javascript language.

As the page you linked to states, normally you'll get instances of `File` from a `<input type="file" />`. Since Node.js isn't run in a browser, it does not implement any of the browser APIs and as such, does not implement `File`. If you want to handle files in Node.js, check out the built-in [File System module (`fs`)](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

No, due to NodeJS not running in a browser and this being a type defined by the browser it is not available in NodeJS. Use fs instead for files.

Answer (score 0):

`File` is only available in node version 20.x.x or later, here is a comment from a Zod GitHub issue:

**Reason and Solution**
Using `z.instanceof(File)` or anything similar throws File is not defined error, because the File class is only available on node-v20.0.0 or upper (related PR). so if your node is lower than this, and you're trying to run the code on the node environment instead of the browser, it'll throw the File is not defined error. The same goes with `FileList`.
So the solution would be to upgrade your node version to the latest one. and if you cannot afford that, u can try using the `@web-std/file` library and use the File class they provide

**Edit**
I tried using file `instanceof` File where File is coming from `@web-std/file`, and seems it returns false even if file is actually a file. So most probably `z.instanceof(File)` will also behave the same. might be an issue from `@web-std/file`. So the only solution left for now is to upgrade your node to `v-20.0.0` or upper

Source: https://github.com/colinhacks/zod/issues/387#issuecomment-1774603011